# Maximum size of an index in bits?

Tags: computer-architecture

> An indexed file contains at most $2^6$ records. The indexed file is stored in a memory with $2^{14}$ cells. What is the maximum size of the index in bits?

If I would like to find the maximum size of the memory in bits I can simply just:

> $2^{14} \ast 8 \text{ bit } = 131072 \text{ bit}$

I found the solution but no explanation was given to it:

> 6 + 14 = 20 bits
>
> For each entry: $2^6 \ast 20 = 64 \text{ bits } \ast 20 \text{ bits}$
>
> Result being: 1280 bits

I know that an Index contains a list of keys stored in the file together with entries that point to where the record containing each key is stored. It is the very first thing to be transferred to the memory to allow memory access to these records.

Comment: 64 bits times 20 bits is *not* 1280 bits.

Comment: I don't know where the 6 comes from (perhaps the size of a cell?), but the calculation is: 20 bits are needed per index, and there are 64 indices (one per record), so 20 times 64 equals 1280.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus thanks for your reply. This is a computer science exam question for which I don't have any clue how the numbers came to be.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus there is only one index in an indexed file that contains a list of assumed unique keys. In this case, the index file would have 6 different keys for each entry.

Now, my question is what formula allow us to pick 2$6$ and 2$14$ and get this result. If I use this: 
> 2$6$ * 2$14$ = 2$6$+$14$ = 2$20$
Mathematically speaking it makes sense but unfortunately doesn't make too much sense from what I've learnt till now.

Comment: If you're thinking in terms of formulas then you're thinking in the wrong way. Think of it this way: suppose you were in charge of designing the file format for this indexed file. How many bits would you have to allocate for indices?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, I undersood it now. I would have to allocate in advance 20 bits per each key, address pair in the Index file before moving the contents of the indexed file into memory for easier access to the content.  After thinking about your question, I ended up having it correct when I presented it to the lecture but he even said that the question was too abstracted and we would've to assume how many bits each record would hold at minimum to have an unique key. 

Thanks a lot !